# Not able to upload data to aws s3 bucket from localhost?

Tags: php, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3

Do we have to provide Bucket with any permission to dynamically upload video to aws s3 bucket?

Comment: Is the bucket public with creating object permission?

Comment: No it is not public.

Comment: Do you want to upload videos from a web application or from a server?

Comment: For tips on asking a good question, please see: [How do I ask a good question?](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask). Feel free to Edit your question to provide more details.

Answer (score 1):

In node.js, you can use the aws-sdk package. The package provides you with a method to enter the 'access key' and 'secret key'. After that you can use the other methods to upload the contents to the bucket without any problems.

Here is the package link:

https://www.npmjs.com/package/aws-sdk

This is a direct example from amazon developer website for php usage. 
I hope it helps.

https://docs.aws.amazon.com/aws-sdk-php/v3/guide/examples/s3-examples-creating-buckets.html

Comment: i am using php-sdk

Answer (score 1):

yes, all buckets are private by default - you need to either grant the world access (which I don't recommend), or else provide IAM credentials that have sufficient access to put objects to the bucket.

Comment: I have searched a lot but I am not getting a clear idea of how to give IAM sufficient access to put objects in the bucket.

Comment: I have changed bucket from not public to public but still i am not able to upload it.